# Prevent clicking on file input's label from opening file browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a form where users can upload images, and I'm using `<label>`s for each input. However, in this particular case it's not desirable for the file browser to open when a user clicks on the label element. I've tried using jQuery's `preventDefault` on the labels, but it doesn't work. Any way to disable this functionality? I'd still like to stick with labels instead of replacing them with other elements.

My HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="userImages" class="nodefault">Please upload images</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" id="userImages" name="userImages" />
    </div>
<div>
```

and my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nodefault").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I'm using:
jQuery v1.10.1
jQueryUI v1.10.3
Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2

Comment: Typo in `.ready()` missing `)` in the end

Comment: That is browser functionality. If you have a label for a file input the browser automatically does the same as clicking on the input field itself. You don't have to do anything to get that behaviour.

Comment: @roasted Yes, he wants to **prevent** that default behaviour. If you want to prevent it, you have to do something.

Comment: @roasted that's because I don't want to prevent the default function from all labels, just file upload ones.

Comment: While removing the `for` attribute would work, it's not an ideal situation for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Ok my bad, for attribute works and e.preventDefault() do the trick...

Comment: So OP, now you have edited your typos, is it working or not?

Comment: It is, but in the end it wasn't a typo (the code here is just the essential parts of much much more code), but actually a weird caching problem I hadn't run into before. The code was working, but my test browsers didn't have the latest version of the JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a Typo in `.ready()` missing `)` in the end

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nodefault").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Works fine Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dpan2/)

Comment: Hmm, so it does. That typo doesn't exist in the actual code, so I guess it wasn't a simple mistake in logic, but an error somewhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ready()` not closed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nodefault").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```