# Why is my asp fileupload control textbox clickable?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a asp fileupload control which works okay on IE8 but now it is making the textbox clickable as well and function same as browse button.

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="id" CssClass="" onchange=""/>
```

Comment: This behavior is by design.

Answer (score 1):

`FileUpload` controls translates into HTML's `input` with `type="file"` control, and what you are experiencing is the default behaviour.

See:  [input type=file - W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html)

If for some reason you want to disable it then you can do:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= id.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

*(the above code taken/modified from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17885918/961113))*

Comment: This is not working for me. I just want user to be able to click on browse button but not on the text box. Using XHTML 1. And the problem is in IE 11

Comment: There is no direct way of doing it, You can have file input with visibility set to null, add a new button, and on the click of that button, stimulate the click on file input. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376452/hide-the-browse-button-on-a-input-type-file